# Why does a method's `this` change when calling a reference to an object's method?

Tags: javascript

```
function Person(gender) {
  this.gender = gender;
}

Person.prototype.sayGender = function()
{
  alert(this.gender);
};

var person1 = new Person('Male');
var genderTeller = person1.sayGender;

person1.sayGender(); // alerts 'Male'
genderTeller(); // alerts undefined
```

Why does genderTeller(); alerts undefined is not clear to me. if I see it I believe it's just same as line above it. Can some please explain the details

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you assign a variable like this...

```
var genderTeller = person1.sayGender;
```

...you lose the *context* of the `person1` object, and the function's `this` points to the global object (`window` in a browser), instead of the instantiated `person1` object.

You get `undefined` because the `gender` property does not exist on `window`, and referencing an undefined property on an object returns `undefined` in JavaScript.

You can fix that in modern browsers with [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)...

```
var genderTeller = person1.sayGender.bind(person1);
```

...or jQuery has a method too called [`proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).

```
var genderTeller = $.proxy(person1.sayGender, person1);
```

Comment: How do we "lose the context of the person1 object" is a bit confusing.

Comment: @sushilbharwani: Because you do not call it straight away, you are just assigning a reference to the function in a variable. This is just how JavaScript works.

Answer (score 5):

This is how JavaScript scope works. I think the following example will give you a good insight.

```
this.gender = 'Female';

function Person(gender) {
  this.gender = gender;
}

Person.prototype.sayGender = function()
{
  alert(this.gender);
};

var person1 = new Person('Male');
var genderTeller = person1.sayGender;

person1.sayGender(); // alerts 'Male'
genderTeller(); // alerts 'Female'
```

---

There is a simple way of figuring out what is the value of `this` in a function you are calling. It is usually the `object` before the the `dot` where you invoked the function. For example:

`person1.sayGender()` here `this` = `person1`

`object1.object2.foo()` here `this` = `object2`

`genderTeller()` here `this` = `window`, because you are not calling it from any object.

Obviously you can set the value of `this` with `.call` or `.apply` function but usually I follow this rule when I build a mental model for my code.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the function without the context of its object, so `this` will be the global object `window`, so the function alerts the value of `window.gender`, which is `undefined`.