# Why does 'this' changes when you stick a method in a variable

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does a method's `this` change when calling a reference to an object's method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657633/why-does-a-methods-this-change-when-calling-a-reference-to-an-objects-method)

I thought I knew a little JavaScript but I just noticed that if you execute a method from a variable it will change this. I tried to find information about this but most articles talk about call, apply, bind, event handlers/callbacks, etc.

```
var dog = {

  bark: function(){
    console.log('woof');
  },

  speak: function(){
    this.bark();
  }

};

// Test 1
dog.speak(); //woof


// Test 3
var speak = dog.speak
speak(); //TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'bark'
```

Comment: Have a look at the [MDN documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)... you are changing the way you call the function. From an object method call to a simple function call. Functions are not bound by default.

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate. Voting for close.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to set the `var` as something other than speak. And you need to go:

```
var speaking_var = dog.speak();
speaking_var();
```

Fix your typos (you forgot `;` after `var speak = dog.speak`)

Comment: No, the variable name has nothing to do with it. See my comment and the duplicate question...

Comment: @Felix- What about the missing `;` and `()`?

Comment: `;` are optional in JavaScript and `()` will *call* the function and assign the return value to the variable (not the function to the variable -- what the OP wants). You will actually get an other error, that the value in `speaking_var` is not a function and cannot be called (or something like that).